# Android - Fragment is behind Buttons from Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So I have an activity with 2 empty ListView's and 3 Buttons. The "Hinzufügen" Button (seen in Screenshot) should load a Fragment into a Framelayout (used as Container) to lay over all components (ListView's and Buttons) from the activity. But I don't know why it lays behind all of them (can't click the Button of the Fragment because it's behind an empty ListView).

Screenshot without Fragment started:
https://abload.de/img/dqwdwqemuhi.jpeg

Screenshot with Fragment started:
https://abload.de/img/fewqfewp7u0b.jpeg

If I get the container with

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.container);
```

and then use

```
view.bringtToFront();
```

the Buttons from the activity are still shown but the ListView's are in the background (can click the button from the fragment now).

How do I get the buttons from the activity in the background so that the fragment lays over the whole activity and its components?

Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="superhelden.com.superheldenuebersichtsapp.Activities.DeckOverview">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/addCardsContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="332dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addCards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/addCards"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeCards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/removeCards"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addCards"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/endGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/endGame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.88"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/amountOfTypesList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/deckList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity Java:

```
public class DeckOverview extends AppCompatActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Button addCardsButton;
Button removeCardsButton;
Button endGameButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deck_overview);
    addCardsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCards);
    addCardsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.addCardsContainer, new addCards());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("addCards");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    removeCardsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeCards);
    removeCardsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO: Karten aus Tabelle in der DB entfernen
        }
    });
    endGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endGame);
    endGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EndScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context="superhelden.com.superheldenuebersichtsapp.Fragments.addCards">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/allCardsList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"

    style="@style/Margin_And_Divider_Style"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/selectedCardsList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"

    style="@style/Margin_And_Divider_Style"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/doneButtonAddCards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/done"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="180dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="439dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Java:

```
List<Card> allCardsList;
ListView allCardsListView;

View addCards;

public addCards() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    allCardsList = DbClass.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllCards();
    allCardsListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.allCardsList);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), allCardsList.get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    addCards = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_cards, container, false);

    return addCards;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `addCardsContainer` to the bottom of your `Activity` XML (last child of `ConstraintLayout`). Drawing is always in order of positioning in inflated layout file. `bringToFront` is not for this case

```
    ...
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/addCardsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

because of margin you may still see a fragment of your buttons in layer below. you can replace `layout_margin` with `padding` and set some background for cover

```
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#000000"
```

Comment: Already tried putting it at the bottom but still doesn't work.

Comment: It has to...its clearly a problem with drawing order. could you provide screenshot with this `addCardsContainer` `FrameLayout` moved to bottom?

Comment: https://puu.sh/wf8pS/5f816e267c.png (Screenshot of code) ... https://puu.sh/wf8Mz/0747fe7ab9.png (Screenshot of App with Fragment). Nothing changed as you can see :/

Comment: try with line `android:elevation="20dp"` ( if not working add also `android:background="#000000"`) for your `FrameLayout`. its probably [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) issue - since API21 Buttons have "built-in" elevation (this shadow under view) and in your code are placed in same parent with `addCardsContainer` `FrameLayout`, which don't have any elevation by default and you don't set it. just guessing... :/ container should be last in `ConstraintLayout` anyway as in answer (and above screenshots)

Comment: The elevation was the problem! Thanks!!

Comment: I had the same issue, and 'elevation' was the only solution. Thank you @snachmsm